# Type of Navigator.push() can't be signed to onPressed

Tags: dart, flutter

Im looking through flutter docs and examples and im stuck in the routing.
Here is documentation https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html
It tells I can do a button with function to navigate with `Navigator`

```
onPressed: (context) {
  Navigator.pop(context);
}
```

but my ide (vs code) and debugger doesn't think it is possible. It shows me error when im trying to do it.

```
[dart] The argument type '(dynamic) → Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type '() → void'.
```

Build also fails with exceptions

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framewo…
```

not quite sure what it means...
Any suggestions?

Comment: I doubt the error is from the code you posted

Comment: My ide tell me it is right there https://postimg.org/image/nwbaj6svv/

Comment: But your IDE contains different code than the one you posted in your question.

Comment: Thanks, I just copied code from docs and didn't noticed this change was important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not pass the `context` to `onPressed` as it is a void callback, so it does not return anything. Use it only to execute logic.

Comment: Thanks, thats it. But what if I want to create named function in class that calls Navigator to push something and pass this function to onPressed property? It cause errors with returning type value

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: If I create `goHomeScreen (BuildContext context) async {
    await Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/');
  }` function to (await because its future, right?) I get error that function doesn't return voidCallback

Comment: `onPressed: ()=>goHomeScreen(context)`

Comment: Thanks, thats helpful

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass `context` to the `onPressed` callback, `context` is available inside the callback anyway if the callback is created in a scope where `context` is available:

```
build(BuildContext context) {
  ... 
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }
}
```